# Destroying a multiple dialog box

Tags: jquery, dialog

Hii,
I have a problem in using dialog box in jquery.At a point of time an event may trigger that displays a dialog box,before this dialog box closes, another event may trigger which displays a new dialog box.

Till now I am closing the dialog box explicitly before another dialog box opens by using destroy for each id.

```
   if($('#'+errorId).dialog("isOpen"))
                $('#'+errorId).dialog("destroy");
if($('#'+successId).dialog("isOpen"))
            $('#'+successId).dialog("destroy");
```

What I need is to close all dialog boxes at one go instead of one at a time.
Is this kind of solution possible?if Yes please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.
With Regards
Phani Kumar

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Computers do things one at a time; that's how they work. (Yes, we have parallel computers, but you can't yet do things in parallel using Javascript.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a class X say 'dialog' on each of the containers opened as a dialog and 
then call $`('.dialog').dialog('close')`

Comment: I have tried the solution you have given and it worked.
Now will re-factor my code.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution would be to store the jQuery-Object references in an array as global variable. For instance:

```
globalarray = new Array();
var jDialog = jQuery('selector').dialog({
   parameters: go here
});    
globalarray.push(jDialog);
```

With that approach, you'd have presentation and logic seperated and you could simply iterate over the array with the following:

```
function destroy_all_dialogs() {
   var max_length = i.length
   for (var i=0; i<max_length; ++i) {
      var jDialog = globalarray[i];
      jDialog.dialog('destroy');
   }
}
```

Notice that this is a simplistic solution. If you want to be more specific (maybe close only dialogs of a specific context), you'd need a more complex object to manage that. Also, I split everything up into variables for better understanding of every single step, but you can group some statements together if there are too many variables for you ;)

#### NOTE

If your trigger is set up in a way that it always triggers before closing, you have to remove the trigger before closing. You can add that to the `destroy_all_dialogs` function.

Comment: Hello Mike,
Thanks for the solution you have given but i got an easier way to solve the problem.Once again Thank you very much for responding.